# Expanding brackets to power of -1/2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you expand this?

$$ \left(16-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{-\frac12} $$

And generally how would you expand any $ (a+b)^n $ including fractional and negative powers.

Comment: Does it being like $1/sqrt(n)$, where n is the stuff inside the brackets, have anything to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean by expand? In this case there is no finite expansion, but one has to do something else, like a [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

Comment: I could expand $(a + b)^n$ where n is positive integer, but in this case n isn't. Should i just leave this as is? And that looks a little complex...

Comment: It all depends on what your goal is. What does the exercise say (if it is an exercise)?

Comment: If you're looking for a simplified answer, consider $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{64-x^2}{4}}} $= $\sqrt{\frac{4}{64-x^2}}$ = $\frac{2}{64-x^2}$

Comment: Interesting. Wont the denominator of the 3rd bit be square rooted to?

Comment: @zahbaz That last equality doesn't hold.

Comment: And yes @Dylanthepiguy

Comment: Thanks. It ought to be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{64-x^2}}$. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thanks. you can put it in te answers if you want ill mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we simplify
$$ f(x)=\left(16-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{-\frac12}= \left(\frac{64-x^2}{4}\right)^{-\frac12} = 2\left(64-x^2\right)^{-\frac12} $$
Then we expand
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\frac{x}{1!}\frac{d}{dx}f(0) + \frac{x^2}{2!}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(0) + \cdots 
$$
Note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 2x\left(64-x^2\right)^{-\frac32}$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) = 4\left(x^2+32\right)\left(64-x^2\right)^{-\frac52}$$
So now we have
$$ f(0) = 2\left(64\right)^{-\frac12} = \frac14 $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(0) = 0 $$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(0) = 4\left(32\right)\left(64\right)^{-\frac52} = \frac1{256}$$
Therefore, by Maclaurin series expansion we have
$$ f(x)=2\left(64-x^2\right)^{-\frac12} = \frac14+ \frac{x^2}{512} + O(x^3)  $$
You are free to expand to any degree that you wish.

Comment: Why not $2\sqrt{(64-x^2)}\over {64-x^2}$ ? I know that it's the same thing but usually we don't let radicals at the denominator

Comment: @RenatoFaraone, there's nothing wrong with radical denominators. It's simply a matter of preference at this point.

Comment: Could you also say that this isn't expanding, just simplifying.